# Customized theme seems not working on Android 4.2

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme

I am trying to customize the ActionBar background color to white. Using the code  `actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(whiteclor....);` works without problem. When I try using style, it seems not working on android 4.2. Any idea?

styles.xml under values,

```
<!-- customized theme -->
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TabBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TabView</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TabText</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar">
    <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

style.xml under v14

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
        res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tc"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think its because the parent of your custom actionbar is not deriving from AppCompat, Try changing

```
<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar">
```

to

```
<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:displayOptions"></item>
    <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item>


    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks. It is still the light grey background, not white.

Comment: Updated my answer can you pls check

Comment: not working. Btw, have to remove the last background item you added, as it throw " error: Error: Color types not allowed (at 'background' with value '#ffffff')"

Comment: try using a color resource for the last background